# How can I change the names of the items in the side toc (DocFX)

Tags: c#, .net, docfx

I am working with docfx, and I would like to change the title of the items in the side table of contents.

I know that for this I need to generate a new toc.yml file in the api subfolder when I run the following command:
`docfx docfx_project/docfx.json`.

So my question is how to modify the docfx.json file in order to modify the toc.yml file in the api subfolder?

Comment: Does this help? Overwrite files in DocFx: https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/intro_overwrite_files.html

Comment: This may also help: https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/848

Comment: @hcdocs thanks for the links but I still don't get it. I tried to only change the name of one item of the TOC in api documentation creating an overwrite file but no change appears.
I want to only overwrite the file toc.yml in the api folder.